# Cloud Foundry with Spring Boot

Tags: cloud, spring-boot

I am getting the following error when I am trying to push the Spring Boot application:

```
C:\WORKSPACES>cf push spr_boot_first
Creating app spr_boot_first in org k.agwl.org / space development_space_one  
as
 k.agwl@gmail.com...
OK

Using route spr-boot-first.cfapps.io
Binding spr-boot-first.cfapps.io to spr_boot_first...
OK

Uploading spr_boot_first...
FAILED
Error uploading application.
read C:\WORKSPACES\.metadata\.lock: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not using the Cloud foundry plugin from eclipse,but are doing the push from the command line.

Close eclipse and try the push from the command line again.

Or install the tooling from the marketplace:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cloud-foundry-integration-eclipse

Comment: Hi Robert, Thanks for your comment,,,, Could you tell me how to add cloud foundry plugin for Eclipse,     Also, tell me how to do it from tooling as you told...

Comment: Hi Robert,   I am trying to do it through command line after closing my STS, as suggested by you,,, but now i am getting a new error :

Comment: C:\WORKSPACES>cf push spr_bt_first
Creating app spr_bt_first in org kar.agwl.org / space development_space_one as k.agwl@gmail.com...
OK

Creating route spr-bt-first.cfapps.io...
OK

Binding spr-bt-first.cfapps.io to spr_bt_first...
OK

Uploading spr_bt_first...
Uploading app files from: C:\WORKSPACES
Uploading 16.6M, 406 files
Done uploading
FAILED
Error uploading application.
Server error, status code: 502, error code: 0, message:

Comment: Post another question, look around the internet.  There are lost of things related to this 502 error, including taking longer than 5 minutes to do the upload.  If I helped you mark my answer or at least upvote it :).